# How to get date and time separately from Outlook MailItem in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to get SentOn as both a short date and a short time. How can I do that?

```
$mailbox = "my.mailbox@example.com"

$outlook = New-Object -com Outlook.Application
$ns = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$inbox = $ns.Folders.Item($mailbox).Folders.Item("Inbox")
$searchItems = $inbox.Folders.Item("MySubFolder").Folders.Item("MyNestedSubFolder").Items
$searchItems | Select Subject, SentOn.ToShortTimeString()
```

This gives an error `SentOn : The term 'SentOn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

I also tried `$searchItems | Select Subject, [datetime](SentOn).ToShortTimeString()` but got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon inspection in the loop the property `SentOn` is of `System.DateTime` type so there is no reason to recast. Now you want to use a method from that type to change the property output. As you have seen you cannot edit the properties dynamically as you have done.

[Calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) would fit nicely here as they are designed for that purpose.

```
select Subject, @{Name="SentOn";Expression={($_.SentOn).ToShortDateString()}}
```

If you need to change more properties than just the SentOn just add on more calculated properties separated with commas. Just like you would with normal preexisting properties.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$searchItems | %{[pscustomobject]@{
                     Subject=$_.Subject; 
                     ShortTime=(get-date $_.SentOn.DateTime).ToShortTimeString();
                     ShortDate=(get-date $_.SentOn.DateTime).ToShortDateString()}
                 }
```

Comment: You don't need to build new objects with unnecessary calls when the current object already has what you need.